# Octave skip parameter

Tags: matlab, function, parameters, octave

I have following problem:

I want to use following function from Octave "pcg" defined as:

x = pcg (A, b, tol, maxit, m1, m2, x0, …)

The documentation says:

"m = m1 * m2 is the (left) preconditioning matrix, so that the iteration is (theoretically) equivalent to solving by pcg P * x = m \ b, with P = m \ A. Note that a proper choice of the preconditioner may dramatically improve the overall performance of the method. Instead of matrices m1 and m2, the user may pass two functions which return the results of applying the inverse of m1 and m2 to a vector (usually this is the preferred way of using the preconditioner). If m1 is omitted or empty [] then no preconditioning is applied. If m2 is omitted, m = m1 will be used as a preconditioner."

Now i got all parameters but i don't have m2 and I want to leave this one out. Like the documentation says "omit" it so m = m1.

I could not find a way to omit this parameter in octave.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Omit means leave it out. Don’t give the parameter. Write `pcg(A,b,tol,maxit,m1)`.

Comment: yes I know that but I want to set x0 after I omitted m2. Thats my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 6 in [the documentation for `pcg`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/pcg.html) is:

```
[x, flag, relres, iter, resvec, eigest] = ...
     pcg (A, b, [], [], "apply_m", [], [], 3)
```

Here, `”apply_m”` is the input argument `m1`, and for `m2` they have filled out `[]` to be able to provide a later parameter.

Thus, to give parameter `x0` but omit `m1` you should be able to say:

```
x = pcg (A, b, tol, maxit, m1, [], x0, …)
```