# Octave: Unable to pass optional arguments into VBA function (when adding excel sheets via COM server)

Tags: excel, octave, activex

I'm attempting to add sheets to an excel file.

It should be fairly straightforward; however, the following minimal working example below fails when attempting to skip optional arguments using empty braces. (Is this not correct? [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778952/octave-skip-parameter) [Source 2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-methods.html))

```
clc
clear

% if COM error occurs, excel process remains open.
% use task manager to end process, else 'a.xlsx' file remains "in use".

srvr = actxserver('excel.application');
wbks = srvr.workbooks;

pth  = fullfile(pwd, 'a.xlsx');

if ~exist(pth, 'file')

  wbk = wbks.add;
  wbk.activate;
  wbk.saveAs( pth );
  wbk.close;

end

wbk = wbks.open( pth, 0, false );
wbk.activate;

wshts    = wbk.worksheets;

shts     = wbk.sheets;

wsht     = wshts.item(1);
wsht.activate;

sht      = shts.item(1);

wsht.select(true);
sht.select(true);

%{
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add
%}

shts.add(sht);     % functions
shts.add(wsht);    % functions

shts.add([],sht);  % fails
shts.add([],wsht); % fails


shts.count

wbk.save;

srvr.quit;
```

Here is the error:

```
error: com_invoke: property/method invocation on the COM object failed with error `0x800a03ec' - Z
error: called from
    trash at line 46 column 1
```

Note that the `add` functions until skipping the first input. Are square brackets the wrong method to skip an input?

[Original source](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2603-add-a-new-excel-sheet-from-matlab).

I have also posted this in [Octave forum](https://octave.discourse.group/t/unable-to-pass-optional-arguments-into-vba-function-when-adding-excel-sheets-via-com-server/798).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you split the 'chained' operation into two separate ones with an intermediate variable? (i.e. `wsht = wshts.item(1); wsht.select(true); wshts.add( [], wsht, 2 );` )

Comment: Haha, no — I have that in the official code and I thought someone would complain that I was complicating by combining, so I simplified for this question. Neither works :/

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Realized the add function works until skipping first input. Is this a syntax issue for skipping inputs? Updated code to demonstrate.

Comment: Updated the question to make it about optional input arguments.

Comment: it wasn't about "complicating" per se :p , I'm just aware that if the class is of the 'old style', then the "dot access" syntax is actually something one implements on top (as it's not the 'natural' access style in old-style classes), and occasionally the implementation might get buggy when multiple accesses are performed like this. It may be worth trying the 'normal' interface, i.e. calling the 'invoke' command as specified here: https://octave.sourceforge.io/windows/package_doc/COM-Interface.html#g_t_0040octave_005fcom_005fobject_002finvoke.

Comment: As for whether the error is due to default arguments, and whether this is the right syntax: I can't test personally as I'm not on windows, but the source code of the package would seem to suggest that a) yes the reason you're getting the error has something to do with what is being called, presumably the default argument (see windows-1.6.0/rc/__COM__.cc:887) and b) that in theory an empty matrix is converted to an "Empty" object when passed to the com interface (see windows-1.6.0/rc/__COM__.cc:806). It would seem reasonable that passing an empty input would trigger the default argument, but...

Comment: The dot syntax just invokes the `com_invoke` command from the `windows` package, but I had similar thoughts about using the fully written command and I can confirm that I tested it and it provides the same outcome. `invoke` also provides the same output.

Comment: More clearly, `invoke` actually calls `com_invoke`, so they are identical. `com_invoke(shts,'add','[]','wsht')` or `com_invoke(shts,'add','[]',wsht)` all fail out with the same listed error.

Comment: what about `com_invoke(shts,'add',[],wsht)`?

Comment: in any case, if the above doesn't work, then I would [file a bug](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs.html). Actually, I would file a bug regardless, since at the very least, even if the above does work, how to call with default arguments properly should still be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: octave forum determined likely culprit. referred me to bug reporting forum. `windows` package creator notified. changed bug report to feature request. committed changes. will appear in next octave update. thank you for your help. if you post - it's a bug, report it, the answer is yours : j

Comment: reported bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments under the question,
this was a bug, which [has been reported](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60098) by OP and [fixed in the development branch](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/windows/ci/ac7a22f8ebd0fbcd709c90cb7ef19dd98fd28332/).